# How to find which senders use the most space in my Gmail account?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap, sql

How could I sort email senders (distinct "from" addresses) by the total amount of space each sender's cumulative messages (including bodies and attachments) are occupying in my Gmail account? I'm thinking something like:

1. Download all my messages to a local client such as Thunderbird via IMAP
2. Somehow convert the email data into a database that can be queried
3. Use something like SQL to query the database and get total message size per sender

Can anyone help me flesh this out a bit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it in **Thunderbird** without external software.

**Step 1: Get the data**

Either go into **Google Takeout** (https://takeout.google.com/) and download a complete copy of all your Gmail messages. You'll get everything in MBOX format which you can then import into the client.

*OR*, configure the client to directly download the messages using **IMAP**.

**Step 2: Group the Emails**

Go to your Inbox, select in the upper right corner the icon for ***Message Display List Options*** and select ***Table View***

Select the same icon again, and in the ***Sort By*** option, select ***From***

Finally, Select the same icon again, and in the ***Sort By*** option, select ***Grouped by Sort***

**Step 3: Review the Data**

Click on each group. On the message preview side, at the bottom, you'll get a prompt with the ***accumulated size*** of that group of emails.

For example, it will say something like *"These messages take up 4.7 KB."*

Comment: IMAP would probably be better here, OP can then delete and otherwise manage emails directly rather than having to return to gmail's web interface and find each message.

Answer (score 3):

I use a script to do basically that. While it's not directly shareable on superuser, here are the basic steps it performs:

- Connect to the server through IMAP¹
- `SELECT` a given folder²
- `SEARCH` emails from a given range `((SINCE "<date>") (NOT DELETED))`
- `FETCH` for each email³ the fields `(RFC822.SIZE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])`
- Group the results by source, summing the sizes
- Sort and print the result

For a one-off run you could even do that manually on a single session (that you are copying to a file for later parsing). Remember that IMAP requires you to prefix every command with an (arbitrary) tag,⁴ and that the reply will have that same tag, but there may be intermixed untagged responses as well.

The session may look like this:

```
* OK Gimap ready for requests
x1 LOGIN myusername mypassword
x1 OK LOGIN completed.
x2 SELECT INBOX
* 1234 EXISTS
* 11 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft)] Permanent flags
* OK [UNSEEN 1203] Is the first unseen message
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 65530] The next unique identifier value
x3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
x4 UID FETCH 1:65530 (RFC822.SIZE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])
* 1 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 9999 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)] {43}
From: "Jon Postel" <jpostel@example.com>

 UID 3522)
* 2 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 9989 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)] {76}
From: "Super user question"
  <superuserquestion1826542@invalid-email.com>

 UID 7476)
* 3 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 9889 BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)] {70}
From: "Stack Exchange"
  <question1826542superuser@invalid-email.com>

 UID 8084)
...
x5 LOGOUT
* BYE Logout Requested
```

Note: The email sizes above are 9999, 9989 and 9889. The `UID FETCH` on the range 1:65530 is based on UIDNEXT being 65530.

¹ Easiest way in Gmail today would be to use an application password. That's currently only available with 2FA enabled.

² In your case you would be interested in the special "All mails" “folder” of Gmail. Use one with just a few items for testing.

³ Actually in batches of 100 emails.

⁴ x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 on the sample

Comment: In case anyone is curious, see the following link for a description of IMAP extensions provided by Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions